# Sum of the series $~\sum_{k=0}^{n}k \cdot {2n \choose k} .$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

We have to find the summation of the finite series $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k \cdot {2n \choose k} .$$
Now notice that, if the sum was $~~\sum_{k=0}^{n}k \cdot {n \choose k} ~~$ then we take $~f(x)=(1+x)^n~$ and then do derivative on both side after taking the corresponding binomial expansion. But how should I approach for the given series $~~\sum_{k=0}^{n}k \cdot {2n \choose k} .$.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k \cdot {2n \choose k} =\sum_{k=1}^{n}k \cdot {2n \choose k} =\sum_{k=1}^{n}k \frac{2n}{k}\cdot{2n-1 \choose k-1} \\=n\cdot2\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n} {2n-1 \choose k-1} \\=n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cdot {2n-1 \choose k-1}+n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n} {2n-1 \choose 2n-k} \\=n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{2n} {2n-1 \choose k-1}\\=n\cdot2^{2n-1}$$